# close dask client and cluster when catching any errors or exceptions

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

I am writing a python function to do data processing with dask. I want to automatically close the dask cluster and client if any errors or exceptions raised. So I use the `with ... as:` statement. The function structure is:

```
def func(input:str, # path to input
         output:str, # path to output
        ):
    with LocalCluster() as cluster, Client(cluster) as client:
        # load the input with dask
        # set up computing graph
        da.compute([...])
```

The cluster and client are successfully closed if I make a KeyboardInterrupt when the data are processing, i.e, `da.compute()`. However, when the program is setting up the cluster, i.e, calling `LocalCluster()`, the cluster are not successfully closed when I make an interrupt. I will get something as:

```
......
KeyboardInterrupt: 
2023-10-20 18:55:38,520 - distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker
2023-10-20 18:55:38,523 - distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker
2023-10-20 18:55:38,529 - distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker
2023-10-20 18:55:38,532 - distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker
2023-10-20 18:55:38,535 - distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker
2023-10-20 18:55:38,548 - distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker
2023-10-20 18:55:38,549 - distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker
2023-10-20 18:55:38,556 - distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker
```

The worker are not stopped.

So, the next time when I run this function again, I will get:

```
/users/kangl/miniconda3/envs/work/lib/python3.10/site-packages/distributed/node.py:182: UserWarning: Port 8787 is already in use.
Perhaps you already have a cluster running?
Hosting the HTTP server on port 37963 instead
  warnings.warn(
```

since the previous cluster is not closed.

Any method to automatically close the cluster when interrupt happens during creating the LocalCluster?

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure this would require a deep code change in distributed to achieve. The way that `with` works, the context is only set up once `LocalCluster()` completes, so if you interrupt before then, there is no context yet to safely exit out of.

One thing you might experiment with is

```
cluster = LocalCluster(n_workers=0, ...)
with cluster:
    cluster.scale(...)
    # cluster.wait_for_workers(...) # if you need it
    with Client(cluster) as client:
        compute(...)
```

where now the slow line happens inside a context.